# Quick uses for scripting languages?

Tags: scripting

I feel that there are a lot of quick uses for scripting languages that you may only think of if you have the shell open at all times. I leave a terminal tab open with python running and have solved many problems with a few lines of code typed off the top of my head. What are some of your less obvious uses for the scripting language of your choice.

Comment: I also use Python this way.  I use Python as a shell more often than I use Bash.  :)

Comment: Took screenshots of a bunch of websites, made thumbnails with cool effects (alpha reflection and perspective transform) for portfolio page lightbox gallery thing using py, moz, bash, and imagemagick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most recently in my Windows centric world I have used it to rename large numbers of files, search/filter log files for a specific occurrence, perform network diagnostics, and a host of smaller things I can't think of at the moment that some of my colleagues not having a UNIX background would never have thought of.

Answer (score 1):

I just used a Lua script in SciTE to take a selected SVG path and do some operations on it (find min values and translate to 0, scale, round up values to avoid having a ton of decimal digits). It is just handy.

Answer (score 0):

- Reformat text is some complicated way;
- Prepare some text based on a template logic;
- Rename multiple files (e.g. music collection or photos);
- etc.

Answer (score 0):

Something very similar was discussed in the Wikibooks article [Ad Hoc Data Analysis From The Command Line](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ad_Hoc_Data_Analysis_From_The_Unix_Command_Line).

This mostly discusses the use of Unix commands rather than scripting languages, but the principle is the same ... have a shell open at all times.

Answer (score 0):

Use [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) to clean up some HTML.